# Minimal protobuf c++ installation for CMake use

Tags: cmake, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to use the CMake functions `protobuf_generate` in one of my projects. However, I'd like to the build as lightweight as possible. If at all possible I'd like to do this without having to compile protobuf's source code, or install some package on my (windows) machine.

Is there a way to just download binaries and headers and tell CMake: "Here is everything you need", so I can swap new proto versions whenever I feel like?

Answer (score 0):

```
# CMakeList.txt : Top-level CMake project file, do global configuration
# and include sub-projects here.
#
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.5)

project ("CMakeProject1")
set(TARGET_NAME CMakeProject1)

SET(PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIR "/path/to/include") 
SET(PROTOBUF_LIBRARY "/path/to/libprotobuf.lib") 
SET(PROTOBUF_PROTOC_EXECUTABLE "/path/to/protoc.exe") 

find_package(Protobuf)

protobuf_generate_cpp(PROTO_SRCS PROTO_HDRS path/to/some_object.proto)

add_library(${TARGET_NAME} STATIC ${PROTO_SRCS} ${PROTO_HDRS})
```